# If I hard reset my tablet/phone well I lose everything even if I loved into Google

Tags: factory-reset

So I want to hard reset my tablet. Well I end up losing all of my data even if i logged on to Google. Please let me know asap(as soon as possible).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you logged into Google (since you're forced to do so when you set up your phone), the states of your apps should be backed up. If you used Google Photos and at least used the app once, your important stuff should be saved. It should be noted not everything on the device will be backed up to Google, though.